# Excel VBA: How to transform this kind of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure if the title is correct. Please correct me if you have a better idea.

Here is my problem: Please see the picture.
[image]

This excel sheet contains only one column, let's say ColumnA. In ColumnA there are some cells repeat themselvs in the continued cells twice or three times (or even more).

I want to have the excel sheet transformed according to those repeated cells. For those items which repeat three times or more, keep only two of them.

[Shown in the right part of the picture. There are three Bs originally, target is  just keep two Bs and delete the rest Bs.]

It's a very difficult task for me. To make it easier, it's no need to delete the empty rows after transformation.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

#

**Update:**

Please see the picture. Please dont delete the items if they show again...
[image]

Comment: For the cells that repeat three times, do you want to keep the repeated values in the original data, or can the third duplicate be deleted?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda Thanks for the hint. Sorry I did not say it clearly. I want to have just two repeated items as a result, no matter how many times they repeat originally.

Comment: Didn't analysed your problem in full, but according to what I understand [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691891/how-can-i-transform-a-list-with-titles-into-a-table/38697462#38697462) may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED - SEE BELOW** Try this. Data is assumed to be in "Sheet1", and ordered data is written to "Results". I named your repeted data (A, B, C, etc) as sMarker, and values in between as sInsideTheMarker. If markers are not consecutive, the code will fail.

```
Private Sub ReOrderData()
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sMarker As String
Dim sInsideTheMarker As String

'Get number of rows with data:
lLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

j = 0
k = 1
a = 2
'Scan all rows with data:
For i = 1 To lLastRow
    If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value) Then 'If two consecutive cells holds the same value
        j = j + 1
        If j = 1 Then
            k = k + 1
            a = 2
            sMarker = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Results").Cells(k, 1).Value = sMarker
        End If
    Else 'If not same values in consecutive cells
        sInsideTheMarker = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Results").Cells(k, a).Value = sInsideTheMarker
        a = a + 1
        j = 0
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**EDITION:**  If you want results in the same sheet ("Sheet1"), and keep the empty rows for results to look exactly as your question, try the following

```
Private Sub ReOrderData()
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sMarker As String
Dim sInsideTheMarker As String

'Get number of rows with data:
lLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

j = 0
k = 1
a = 5
'Scan all rows with data:
For i = 1 To lLastRow
    If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value) Then 'If two consecutive cells holds the same value
        j = j + 1
        If j = 1 Then
            k = i
            a = 5
            sMarker = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 4).Value = sMarker
        End If
    Else 'If not same values in consecutive cells
        sInsideTheMarker = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, a).Value = sInsideTheMarker
        a = a + 1
        j = 0
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you so much! Maybe a small tip failure, I changed from k=0 to k= 1. Excellent! Thank you again!

Comment: And please also note that there is no need to use an intermediate variable (`sMarker` and `sInsideTheMarker`): you can shorten the code by writing `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, a).Value=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value` (and the like for sMarker). But I thought the code would be more readable using that intermediate step.

Answer (score 1):

If you can delete the values that have more than two counts, then I suggest that this might work:

```
Sub count_macro()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = 1

While Cells(a, 1) <> ""

    b = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A1000"), Cells(a, 1))

    If b > 2 Then
        Cells(a, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

    b = 0
    a = a + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and the hint. Actually I still have repeated items in the column, but they have different values. Please see the second picture I just posted. But it's a great idea as the first step to reduce the repeated items.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It takes input in column A starting in Row 2 until it ends, and ignores more than 2 same consecutive values. Then it copies them in sets and pastes them transposed. If your data is in a different column and row, change the `sourceRange` variable and the `i` variable accordingly.

```
Sub SETranspose()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sourceRange As range
Dim copyRange As range
Dim myCell As range



Set sourceRange = range("A2", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))

Dim startCell As range

Set startCell = sourceRange(1, 1)

Dim i As Integer
Dim haveTwo As Boolean
haveTwo = True

For i = 3 To Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Cells(i, 1).Value = startCell.Value Then
    If haveTwo Then
        range(startCell, Cells(i, 1)).Copy
        startCell.Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        haveTwo = False
    End If
    End If
    'if the letter changes or end of set, then copy the set over
    'If LCase(Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 1)) <> LCase(startCell.Value) Or _
                'i = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 Then
    If Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) > 1 Then
        Set copyRange = Cells(i, 1)
        copyRange.Copy
        Cells(startCell.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        'Set startCell = sourceRange(i - 1, 1)
    ElseIf Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) = 1 And Cells(i, 1).Value <> startCell.Value Then
        Set startCell = sourceRange(i - 1, 1)
        haveTwo = True
    End If

Next i

'clear up data
Set sourceRange = Nothing
Set copyRange = Nothing
Set startCell = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately it doesnot work by me:-(  Does it work on your computer?   If i understand the code correctly, you try to read all the data in one step then transform them in another step? Because I have a huge database, its not easy to read all the data in one step...

Comment: Ahh I see your new updated picture. With the new information, this code will not work for you. Some work came in for me so I may not be able to take a look at this again immediately, but I will keep it in the back of my mind to come back to it.

Comment: It's OK. Thanks. My question is not a urgent one.

Comment: @Rita Take a look at this new code I put up. See if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks! But this time it shows me a long row. :-) But it's OK.  I get the result from CMArg. It works very well. Thank you!