# VBA If then statement + left

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, automation, vba

I'm very new to using VBA, and I am trying to create a code with these rules (Please see image for context):

If Column B cell has the text "GBP", then go across to the Adjacent cell in Column C. If the first 2 letters of the C cell begins with RB, then post the text "Royal Bank of Scotland" in an adjacent Cell D, if the first 2 letters are HC, then post the text "Corporate" in an adjacent Cell D instead.

If Column B cell has the text "USD", then go across to the Adjacent cell in Column C. If the first 2 letters of the C cell begins with JP, then post the text "JPMorgan" in an adjacent Cell D, if the first 2 letters are BO, then post the text "Bank of America" in an adjacent Cell D instead.

I can do all this manually using excel formulas, however, there's quite a lot of information and Im trying to figure out an automated way of doing this.

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY7d7.jpg)

Comment: what image? No image attached, so no context?

Comment: Why do you need the first `if` (related to column B)? It seems that you just have to check the first two letters of column C.

Comment: Anyway, I think you just need to 1) loop through all rows with data, 2) for each row, extract first two letters (`left, 2`), 3) place the `if` statement and write desired output to colum D. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691891/how-can-i-transform-a-list-with-titles-into-a-table/38697462#38697462) can be helpful.

Comment: Better than `if`, use `Replace`, and make use of the conversions that are in rows 26-29 of your example.

Comment: Hi CMArg, good point with regards to column B if statement. I need that if statement because I have set different rules for other items in column B that is not on the example.

Comment: Do consider doing this directly on the worksheet using lookup tables. I question the effectiveness of a VBA solution in this case as the code could well end up containing too many hardcoded data and rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do. The code assumes that the data is in a sheet named "Data", starting in row 3, and the desired replacements are in another sheet named "Replacements". In this last sheet, starting in the firt row, you must fill column A with Currency (GBP or USD), column B with the two letters code (RB, HC and so on) and column C with the desired substitution (Bank of America, etc.). In your current example, there should be 8 rows of data (the 4 lines that appear in lines 26-29, once for GBP and again for USD).

```
Sub ReplaceBankName()
    Dim sReplacementArray() As Variant
    Dim lLastRowReplacements As Integer
    Dim lLastRowData As Integer
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim ValToFind1 As String
    Dim ValToFind2 As String


    lLastRowReplacements = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lLastRowData = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Create an array with replacement data
    For i = 1 To lLastRowReplacements
        ReDim Preserve sReplacementArray(1 To 3, 1 To i)
        sReplacementArray(1, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 1).Value
        sReplacementArray(2, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 2).Value
        sReplacementArray(3, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 3).Value
    Next

    'Now array has replacemente data
    'if you wish to know array elements, uncomment next three lines

    'For c = 1 To UBound(sReplacementArray, 2)
    '    MsgBox "Currency: " & sReplacementArray(1, c) & " - BankCode: " & sReplacementArray(2, c) & " - Replacement: " & sReplacementArray(3, c)
    '    Next c

    For i = 3 To lLastRowData 'Scan all rows with data
        'Get values from column B (ValToFind1) and C (ValToFind2, first two letters only)
        ValToFind1 = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
        ValToFind2 = Left(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value, 2)

        'Find those to values in the array, and write the replacement in column D
        For r = 1 To UBound(sReplacementArray, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(sReplacementArray, 2)
                If (sReplacementArray(1, c) = ValToFind1 And sReplacementArray(2, c) = ValToFind2) Then
                    Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 4).Value = sReplacementArray(3, c)
                End If
            Next c
         Next r
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you CMArg, I've just tried it out and it works perfectly. It might look like a strange rule, but it'll save me a lot of time. Now all I'll have to do is update the "Replacement" sheet to get this running properly. I appreciate it!!

Comment: One last thing: With regards to the line" ValToFind2 = Left(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value, 3)", how can I modify it such that the value to find is in the middle.  For Example ABC123D, Where 123 is the value to find, and the first 3 and last character is fixed

Comment: Use `Mid` (take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx). Mid(yourstring,startposition, length). In your case `ValToFind2 = Mid(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value, 3,3`

Comment: Little mistake on start position. Try `ValToFind2 = Mid(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Value, 4,3`

Comment: Great! CMArg, I've tried to modify the reference to the array table in the replacement sheet, but I keep messing it up. How would you change this code such that the replacement table has moved from Columns A B C, to Columns D E F,

Comment: I've Tried the following to change the array:  For i = 1 To lLastRowReplacements
        ReDim Preserve sReplacementArray(5 To 7, 1 To i)
        sReplacementArray(5, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 5).Value
        sReplacementArray(6, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 6).Value
        sReplacementArray(7, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 7).Value

Comment: Not shure if I get you. But I think you're confusing Array Dimensions with Data Address. And they are absolutely different things. In the line `ReDim Preserve sReplacementArray(1 To 3, 1 To i)` we're saying: set dimensions to the two-dimensional-array (number of elements), three elements in one dimension (that accounts for Currency, BankCode and Replacement), and `i` dimensions for the other (number of rows, i.e., number of different conditions). Then you assign the values to the array. The number `1` in this line (`Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 1).Value`) is the column with data.

Comment: So try `For i = 1 To lLastRowReplacements
        ReDim Preserve sReplacementArray(1 To 3, 1 To i)
        sReplacementArray(1, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 5).Value
        sReplacementArray(2, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 6).Value
        sReplacementArray(3, i) = Worksheets("Replacements").Cells(i, 7).Value
    Next`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a formula, but since you asked for VBA:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        For i = 4 To 20
            Select Case Left(.Cells(i, 3), 3)
                Case "RBS"
                    .Cells(i, 4) = "Royal Bank of Scotland"
                Case "HCN"
                    .Cells(i, 4) = "Corporate"
                Case "JPM"
                    .Cells(i, 4) = "JPMorgan"
                Case "BOM"
                    .Cells(i, 4) = "Bank of America"
                Case Else
                    MsgBox "This Bank does not exist :-D"
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you Kazschuri, Could you possibly get it to follow an if statement incorporating column B?

Answer (score -1):

In D4, Apply the below formula and drag down

Note: As per the Context/Example, i have taken the first three characters in C column

```
=IF(AND(B4="GBP",LEFT(C4,3)="RBS"),"RoyalBankofScotland",IF(AND(B4="GBP",LEFT(C4,3)="HCN"),"Corporate",IF(AND(B4="GBP",LEFT(C4,3)="JPM"),"JP Morgan",IF(AND(B4="GBP",LEFT(C4,3)="BOM"),"Bank of America",IF(AND(B4="USD",LEFT(C4,3)="RBS"),"RoyalBankofScotland",IF(AND(B4="USD",LEFT(C4,3)="HCN"),"Corporate",IF(AND(B4="USD",LEFT(C4,3)="JPM"),"JP Morgan",IF(AND(B4="USD",LEFT(C4,3)="BOM"),"Bank of America","Not Available"))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you  Karthick, I have done this, but I need something more automated, I'm combining quite a few macros together that I want to run in an order.