# Copy and Paste Values for non-blank values with matching criteria VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling to write the correct code to be able to Copy and Paste Values for non-blank values with matching criteria.
An example of what I'm trying to do can be seen here ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIcMf.png))

What I would like the code to do is to take the values in the left hand range that are not blank, and paste the values into the right hand range where they match according to the labels in row A.

If the new values could paste as a highlighted color that would be helpful as well; however, my main struggle is mainly with the first part. (Picture of how it would look after the macro has run) - ([Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa2ww.png))

I have been able to figure this out by using excel formulas within my code; however, this is not ideal for the functionality of my workbook.

Thanks for the help! - It's much appreciated.

### Update:

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Worksheets("Nielson"‌​).Range("AH3:CD9999")‌​.Formula = "=if(NOT(ISBLANK(vlo‌​okup($a3,Load!$P:$AD,‌​Load!R$4,False))),ife‌​rror(vlookup($a3,Load‌​!$P:$AD,Load!R$4,Fals‌​e),ch3),ch3)"
Worksheets("Nielson"‌​).Range("AH3:CD9999")‌​.Copy 
Worksheets("Nielson"‌​).Range("CH3:CT9999")‌​.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues Worksheets("Nielson"‌​).Range("CH3:CT9999")‌​.Copy
Worksheets("Nielson"‌​).Range("AH3:CD9999")‌​.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 

End Sub
```

<sub>(code posted as comment by OP)</sub>

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: Hi Drew, what code have you got so far?

Comment: Hi Ulli,
I'm still pretty new to VBA so don't have a code worth posting as a solution to my question above as I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet that isn't way off what I want it to do.

Comment: the route i was going before was through vlookups, but like i said in the post, this doesn't work well with my actual workbook.
Sub Button2_Click()
Worksheets("Nielson").Range("AH3:CD9999").Formula = "=if(NOT(ISBLANK(vlookup($a3,Load!$P:$AD,Load!R$4,False))),iferror(vlookup($a3,Load!$P:$AD,Load!R$4,False),ch3),ch3)"


Worksheets("Nielson").Range("AH3:CD9999").Copy
Worksheets("Nielson").Range("CH3:CT9999").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Nielson").Range("CH3:CT9999").Copy
Worksheets("Nielson").Range("AH3:CD9999").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This can help you. Is a modification of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914004/vba-if-then-statement-left/38933122#38933122).

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim vReplacementArray() As Variant
    Dim iLastRowReplacements As Integer
    Dim iLastRowData As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim ValToFind1 As String

    iLastRowReplacements = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    iLastRowData = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

    'Create an array with replacement data (left 6 columns in your example)
    For i = 2 To iLastRowReplacements
        ReDim Preserve vReplacementArray(1 To 6, 1 To i)
        'You can loop here. I leave it hard-coded to make it clearer
        vReplacementArray(1, i) = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 1).Value
        vReplacementArray(2, i) = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 2).Value
        vReplacementArray(3, i) = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 3).Value
        vReplacementArray(4, i) = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 4).Value
        vReplacementArray(5, i) = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 5).Value
        vReplacementArray(6, i) = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 6).Value
    Next


    For i = 2 To iLastRowData 'Scan all rows with data, starting in row 2 (row 1 for titles)
        'Get values from column I (ValToFind1)
        ValToFind1 = Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 9).Value

        'Find those to values in the array, and write the replacement in their respective column
        For c = 1 To UBound(vReplacementArray, 2)
                If (vReplacementArray(1, c) = ValToFind1) Then
                    For j = 1 To 5 'The five columns (J to N in your example)
                        If (vReplacementArray(j + 1, c) <> "") Then 'if there is a value
                            Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 9 + j).Value = vReplacementArray(j + 1, c)
                            Worksheets("Nielson").Cells(i, 9 + j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                        End If
                    Next j
                End If
         Next c

    Next i

End Sub
```